# Return 0 instead of N/A (null) when select count has no results

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I'm want to display a KPI in a singlestat panel, based on the following query:

```
select count(foo) from bar where field = 'value' and time > now() - 1m
```

Sometimes there are no results (and that's valid), but the singlestat panel shows N/A instead of 0

What can/should I do?

Comment: I've tried adding `fill (0)` but that didn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to map `null to 0` under "Value mappings"

[image]

(You dont have to use range to text)

Comment: That's great!
Thank you.

But... now I need this for the Topology plugin too...and it doesn't have the Value Mappings tab :(

Any ideas?

Comment: Sry I don't use that plugin. But you can create a feature request @ there github.  Or try to implement that yourself(and ask a new question it you run into problems)